Setting up threejs and running it
I encountered difficulties while attempting to execute a straightforward Three.js project. Despite adhering to the provided guide, I discovered that I lacked the necessary libraries. Consequently, the project encountered various errors, including typographical errors and overall issues. As a novice, I require a step-by-step guide to comprehend the underlying issues and rectify the errors. Specifically, I am seeking clarification on the areas where I am making mistakes. I am eager to learn and would appreciate assistance in identifying the errors.
I followed any regular youtube tutorial that would allow me to open up a website but i found that the main issue is setting up the libraries which i tried and failed again.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
